# Adding a number to a phrase

Tags: ruby

I can print a raw number with this code:

```
puts 'Please enter your favorite number'
favNumber = gets.chomp
betterNumber  = favNumber.to_i 
puts betterNumber + 1
```

but I need to set a message including the number. I changed the last two lines to this, but it's wrong.

```
betterNumber  = favNumber.to_i + 1
puts 'Your favorite number sucks, a better number is '+ betterNumber + '!'
```

Help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Some advices: 1) Try to be concise in your questions, you basically pasted the same code twice. 2) Always paste the line and exact error you get. 3) In Ruby we use `name_of_variable` for local variables, not `camelCase`. btw, solution: `betterNumber.to_s`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`betterNumber` is of class `Fixnum` and your string is of course of class `String`. You can't add a String and a Fixnum, you need to cast your Fixnum into a String using `to_s`.

```
"Your favorite number sucks, a better number is " + betterNumber.to_s + "!"
```

Also, using interpolation calls `to_s` on any objects being interpolated. So this works, too (and is more common):

```
"Your favorite number sucks, a better number is #{betterNumber}!"
```

Also, in Ruby we usually use `snake_case` variables as opposed to `camelCase` variables. So I recommend using `better_number`

Comment: Thanks guys. I cheated though, look up the answer in the index. But applied in a different situation and i applied it correctly.

Comment: @EyJay can I recommend marking one of these answers as correct information to help others, then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `betterNumber` to a string when printing it, like this: `betterNumber.to_s`.

Comment: Yeah. i never thought it was possible to have 2 methods in 1 object.

gets.chomp.to_i

Thanks guys!